# Super User Moderator Cards

Tags: discussion, design, community

We recently printed some business cards for our Stack Exchange employees and they turned out great.

It got us thinking: our sites' moderators have been working hard to keep our sites high quality for the past few years. They may not be employees, per se, but great community moderators are why our communities are safe, sane, and worth visiting in the first place..

If you're a Superuser moderator, would you be interested in having your own Superuser contact card? Would you find it useful?

I can see them being handy to pass out during your local tech meetups or conferences.

Below is a mockup:

(click on image to see full res version)

[image: Super User moderator card]

Of course Twitter ID/phone# are optional. It can be Skype, AIM, URL etc.

Comment: ooooo me likey.

Comment: The look great... but I'm not sure what I'd use them for. :/

Comment: Can't I have some that say "He's just a plain Super User, but who cares, these cards are awesome" ):

Answer (score 10):

This is actually something that I've been wanting for some time... I would find it useful and would like to have something like that to pass out to other technology and computer enthusiasts that I meet.

Allow the card to be customizable, at least to some degree...

I would suggest changing the `A` (Answer) line to `He is a ♦ moderator on Super User` - for two reasons (changing to `He` to keep the grammar correct).  First, one could argue that 10K+ users are "Community Moderators" since they have access to *some* moderator tools, but are not ♦ mods.  So I would propose using a diamond.

Second, the name of the site is `Super User`, not necessarily `SuperUser.com`, and the `.com` part is already listed on the front of the card...

Just some suggestions...Overall, the design is awesome!

Comment: thanks for the feedback! The cards will be highly customizable (per individual person, card).

Comment: Studiohack I like most of your suggestions, but think using a diamond is confusing to people who aren't familiar with the stack exchange paradigm. The phrase "community moderator" is much more self-explanatory than "what's that diamond thing mean? do you have spades and hearts moderators too or something?"

Answer (score 4):

Looks great, and it would be great to have something to hand out to advertise the site and ourselves. It might be nice if there were a very brief blurb about what Super User is - say:

> He is a Community Moderator on **Super User**, an online Questions and Answers site for computer software and hardware

Comment: OK so I fail at reading - it says that on the front of the card. Derp. Maybe instead there could be some tiny blurb about stack exchange or something?

Answer (score 4):

OK, moderators have officially been mailed the form to obtain the cards. Stay tuned!